# Training Word2Vec with names instead of sentences

Tags: python, nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec

I have scientific database with articles and coauthors.
using this database I am training word2vec model on co-authors.

Use use case here is to disambiguate authors.

I was wondering my approach here can be improved or any suggestions will greatly be appreciated.

[Code](https://github.com/krishnakalyan3/NLP/blob/master/W2V.ipynb)

Comment: Please embed all code natively rather than using external links.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need to use word2vec to disambiguate authors. It might be effective to use regular expressions to parse names and then do a web search.

If you do want to train word2vec to disambiguate authors, it would be better to embed all possible information (e.g., authors, title, journal, abstract, ...).